# How to remove perl reverse extra line

Tags: perl

Could someone point out my mistake?

```
while(<STDIN>){
  my $reverse = reverse $_; #(explicit - to force casting)
  if( 5 <length ){
        print "Reverse is $reverse\n";
  }
  else{
    print; #this will print $_ scalar context
  }
}
```

Execute the program,

```
1234567
Reverse is
7654321
```

but if I change
`print "Reverse is $reverse\n";` to `print "$reverse\n"`

```
1234567

7654321
```

Can someone explain what is going on? and how could I remove the newline?

Comment: [`print`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) doesn't put anything in scalar context. [`print`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) without any arguments prints [`$_`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24_). `my $reverse = reverse $_;` puts [`reverse`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reverse.html) in scalar context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reverse of `"1234567\n"` is `"\n7654321"`. If you want to strip out the newline before reversing, you can use [the built-in `chomp` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html):

```
while(<STDIN>){
  chomp;
  my $reverse = reverse $_; #(explicit - to force casting)
  if( 5 <length ){
        print "Reverse is $reverse\n";
  }
  else{
    print "$_\n"; #this will print $_ scalar context
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add [`chomp;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) as the first line of the loop, and use `say;` or `print "$_\n";` instead of `print;` to compensate for the removed newline.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

while (<>) {
   chomp;
   if( 5 < length ){
      say "".reverse;
   } else {
      say;
   }
}
```